# How do you calculate wasted power in a Line Regulation Test?

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, production-testing

I was curious about this scenario-- there is a voltage regulator we are testing (LM805A) and we have to perform a few tests: No Load, Line Regulation, Load Regulation, and Dropout voltage test.

Beyond comparing to the spec sheet, we have to calculate the wasted power in each test. My question is: how should we go about calculating the wasted power in say the line regulation test where we are changing the input voltage (8V -> 12V) and measuring. My idea was you measure the input and output V & I @ 8V and 12V and calculate the delta of wasted power:

```
    initPowerIn = initVin * abs(initCurrentIn)
    initPowerOut = initVout * abs(initCurrentOut)
    finalPowerIn = finalVout * abs(finalCurrentout)
    finalPowerOut = finalVout * abs(initCurrentOut)
    
    // delta power wasted
    wastedPower = abs( (finalPowerIn - initPowerIn) - (finalPowerOut - initPowerOut)
```

Is this the proper way on going about calculating the wasted power in the test, or am I missing something here? Thanks so much for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you mean by "wasted power" is the power dissipated by the voltage regulator. This is simply the difference between the power input to the regulator and the power applied to the load. Using your notation, it would be equal to initPowerin - initPowerout where again, I assume that init refers to an input voltage of 8 volts. When the input voltage is increased to 12 volts (I assume this is what you mean by final), then the wasted power becomes equal to finalPowerin - finalPowerout. What you have calculated as wasted power is not very meaningful because it combines the results for 2 different conditions: 8 volts in and 12 volts in.

Answer (score 0):

Power "wasted" (W or watts) at any instant is given by
$$ P_W = P_{in} - P_{out} = U_{in}I_{in} -U_{out}I_{out} $$

Energy wasted (J or joules or Ws) in time \$t\$ is given by
$$ E_W = \int _0^t(U_{in}I_{in} -U_{out}I_{out}) dt  $$